# Debian: Automount based on UUID on plugin

Tags: debian, usb, automounting

I've got an `ext4` pen drive whose `UUID` is `bb7522af-2bda-4416-bcca-a076a1cf63a3`.

I want to be able to connect it after boot and mount it to `/home/Shared/Vaderive` (All-user shared).

Is possible directly from GUI or something like `usbmount` or `autofs`?

`uname -a`:

```
Linux HOSTNAME 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u2 (2016-10-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit your `fstab` as follows:

```
UUID=bb7522af-2bda-4416-bcca-a076a1cf63a3 /home/Shared/Vaderive auto defaults,noauto 0 0
```

Create `udev` rules under `/lib/udev/rules.d` to mount/unmount your device e,g:

```
nano /lib/udev/rules.d/automount.rules
```

With the following contents;

```
ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_FS_UUID_ENC}=="bb7522af-2bda-4416-bcca-a076a1cf63a3", RUN+="/bin/mount /dev/%k"
ACTION=="remove", ENV{ID_FS_UUID_ENC}=="bb7522af-2bda-4416-bcca-a076a1cf63a3", RUN+="/bin/umount /dev/%k"
```

Run `udevadm control --reload-rules` then check your files.